# laravel In_array() function part of string detect

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel, php-7

Here is array as following:

```
$array = ['blog.setting', 'blog.post', 'blog.delete', 'blog.edit', 'other.other'];
```

I want to know if there is element which has `'blog.'`;
Maybe like this will be perfect.

```
in_array('blog.*', $array)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? This is a fairly simple task achievable in many different ways.

Comment: well, just looking for the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned Laravel in your tags, you could do:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

$blogTest = Collection::make($array)
    ->contains(function ($elt) {
        return Str::is('blog.*', $elt);
    });
```

Comment: it should detect first word and "blog.", neither middle word nor "blog"

Comment: ["test.setting.random.1", "test.blog.random.2"]  in this case, it should return false. Not true.

Comment: I've just tested it, it returns `false`, you did something wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

You can do with pure PHP like:

```
    $array = ['blog.setting', 'blog.post', 'blog.delete', 'blog.edit', 'other.other'];
    $string = implode(',',$array);

    if (strpos($string, 'blog') !== false) {
        dump('There is blog string inside of given array!');
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: it should detect first word and "blog.", not middle word or "blog"

Answer (score -2):

U need to use regular expression, and `array_filter` method

```
$array = ['blog.setting', 'blog.post', 'blog.delete', 'blog.edit', 'other.other'];

$filtered = array_filter($array, function($value){
    return preg_match('/^blog\..*$/m', $value);
});
```

Comment: One *can* use regex for this, but there is no *need* to do it. Also, this is a very poorly written answer that's more fitting of a comment. No solution and no explanation.

Comment: I thought he will needed these values ​​in the future))